# Odometry error and, maximum and minimum speed

Tags: ros, simulation, simulator-stage, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

First I apologize for my limited English proficiency.
I am programming a simple robot, using Stage to simulate the real world.

First question ( 4 questions to ask the same ):

- How I can define an error for the
  data returned by the odometer?
  (Specifically for the current angle
  in the Z axis msg->
  pose.pose.orientation.z);
- Can it be defined in the .cfg file
  that is passed to Stage?
- Where?
- and Name?

Second question:

- Where I can define the maximum and
  minimum speed of my robot? (Lineal and angular).

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30243/odometry-error-and,-maximum-and-minimum-speed/) by [q2p0](https://answers.ros.org/users/2031/q2p0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [q2p0](https://answers.ros.org/users/2031/q2p0/) on 2012-03-23**:
Ok, question 1 is so much stupid because i can make a function that insert a random error whit the ranges i whant. XD

I make a new (offtopic?) question similar to question 2.
Where I can define the error that make my robot when I publish a rotation angular velocity in the final rotation that i get.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-26**:
@q2p0 Please ask single questions at a time so that answers can be isolated and marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Question number one has a few answers:**

If your measurement error is constant, you can define it using the [ros paramater server](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server) in your [launchfile](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) for your robot. Then read the error paramater from the parameter server and insert it into the orientation covariance matrix in a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html). You probably want to include that message as part of a [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message.

In the following example, the parameter `z_rotation_covariance` is defined in the launchfile:

```
<launch>
  <param name="z_rotation_covariance" value="0.05" />
</launch>
```

To use the parameter value in code, you'll want to use the [rosparam api](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server) for your client.

If your error is a calculated or accumulated error, you will want to set up a [service](http://wiki.ros.org/Services) to calculate the changes as a function on some input and store the error in [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) and another service to retrieve the error from `rosbag` whenever you need to use it in the orientation covariance matrix in a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html). You probably want to include that message as part of a [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message.

You will need to [subscribe](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) to whatever topics are [publishing](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) the parameters of your error estimation function, probably using a [message_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) to combine the messages of several different topics into a single callback. `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` is a good filter for doing this. Then when your filter callback is called, call your error calculation/accumulation service to calculate and store your error, then you can retrieve it from rosbag at any time using your error retrieval service.

**Question number two is simpler:**

You will want to model your robot using [urdf](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf). URDF [joint tags](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint) allow you to specify joint upper and lower limits, efforts, types, etc. You might look into using [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch&cat=connect_ros) instead of Stage. It allows you to add several additional tags to your urdf to model the physics properties of your robot during simulation.

---

Originally posted by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) with karma: 207 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0